# .each breaking if only 1 result - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, each

For some reason, I keep getting an "undefined method 'each'" error every time I try to do the .each do when I have one result in the below.

If I use .inspect, I can see that there's a match.  Does .each work if there's not more than 1 result?  If not, what should I use instead?

```
<% friends = graph.get_object("/me/friends").map{ |hash| hash["id"] } %>

<% User.select([:id]).where(fbookid: friends).each do |common| %>

<% end %>
```

If I just run .inspect on the User.select line (no each), then I get

```
[#<User id: 1>]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

*UPDATE*

Adding additional parameters seemed to allow me to use each...I have no clue why.  It's the same exact result (only 1).

```
User.select([:id, :email, :first_name]).where(fbookid: friends).each do |friend|
```

Comment: I've literally cut all of the other code out.  For these three lines, if I use .each I get the error, and if I use .inspect I get the above.

Answer (score 0):

You get simple object not array so that it's not working. `.each`  method working when if you get `array` you get simple object so that you can use direct means that

for example

```
# if name attributes
User.select([:id]).where(fbookid: friends).name
```

Comment: Is there a solution where I can loop no matter what rather than distinguish between multiple results and one?

Comment: you get 1 record, then how can you use loop ?

Comment: but I might not get one record in the future...that's why I'm asking...I'll have to detect whether there's one user each time?

Comment: User.select([:id]).where(fbookid: friends).class <== print that line what should be return tell me please

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** use each on `User.select([:id]).where(fbookid: friends)`, even if there is only 1 element. It will not raise an exception even if there are no elements.

The error is happening somewhere else. Perhaps you are getting an error on something inside the each loop.

Can you post more code?